# Angular 5 , display json in html

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my project in Angular 5, I want to display in HTML code parameter `"default_price":100`, but my code display all default_price.

**component.ts**

```
   this.ws.getAllProduct().subscribe(
      products => {
          this.products = products.map((product) => {
          return new Product(product);
        });
      }
    );
```

**component.html**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <label for="unit_price" *ngFor="let item of products">{{item.default_price}}</label>
      <input formControlName="unit_price" id="unit_price" type="number" class="validate" placeholder="unit_price">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Json:**

```
{
    "StatusCode": 0, "StatusMessage": "OK", "StatusDescription":
    [
        {
            "product_id": "1",
            "product_name": "Product1",
            "description": "Product1",
            "default_price": 50,
            "lastmoduserid": "31",
            "lastmoddtm": "2018-02-06T13:26:17.000Z",
            "active": 1
        },
        {
            "product_id": "2",
            "product_name": "Product2",
            "description": "Product2",
            "default_price": 60,
            "lastmoduserid": "31",
            "lastmoddtm": "2018-02-06T13:35:17.000Z",
            "active": 1
        },
        {
            "product_id": "3",
            "product_name": "Product3",
            "description": "Product3",
            "default_price": 80,
            "lastmoduserid": "31",
            "lastmoddtm": "2018-02-06T13:35:22.000Z",
            "active": 1
        },
        {
            "product_id": "4",
            "product_name": "Product4",
            "description": "Product4",
            "default_price": 100,
            "lastmoduserid": "31",
            "lastmoddtm": "2018-02-06T13:25:54.000Z",
            "active": 1
        },
        {
            "product_id": "5",
            "product_name": "Product5",
            "description": "Product5",
            "default_price": 120,
            "lastmoduserid": "31",
            "lastmoddtm": "2018-02-06T13:35:27.000Z",
            "active": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to display in html code only `"product_id":"4", "product_name":"Product4"`.

Can you suggest me some idea?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ngFor if you need to display particular object, you can use array.find() to find particular element in the array

Comment: this.ws.getAllProduct().subscribe(
      products => {
       return this.products.find(x => x.product_name === 'Product4')[3];
        });
      }
    );     ----->TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined. Can you help me please?

Comment: then products is not an array

Answer (score 0):

from your json, products.StatusDescription  is the array